# Call to load credentials with FirebaseAdmin does not work

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am working with FirebaseAdmin 1.9.1 and attempting to use the recommended method for this call:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()  
{
  Credential = credential,
});
```

From all that I read, I can load the `credential` paramater via this...

```
var credential = await GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync();
```

or this

```
credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("/your/path/to/glory/google-service-accounts.json");
```

And if the value of a special environment variable is set as so...

```
"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "/your/path/to/glory/google-service-accounts.json",
```

...the two approaches should produce the same, working, result.

Not so! Not so.

The 2nd version works, but the first, recommended, approach? Using GetApplicationDefaultAsync?

Not so much.

I have checked and re-checked, and the two strings containing "/your/path/to/glory/google-service-accounts.json" are identical, though obviously not the value I've pasted here.

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS I copied and pasted directly. And I can see it properly set in the environment variables.

In fact, just to add salt to my wounds, I tried this...

```
credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(_configuration["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]);
```

And the credentials *DID* load.

So... I'm open for suggestions. Talk me off the ledge.

Answer (score 1):

[Doffing my cap to hiranya911](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/130) who talked me off the ledge by asking me the right question.

In replying to him (with my rubber ducky by my side) I realized I was telling him that my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS setting is coming in through secrets, and not environment. Duh. These are not the same!

I moved the setting over to environment from secrets and... problem solved.